# c3.js - How to manually trigger the hover of a donut arc?

Tags: d3.js, charts, c3.js, donut-chart

I'm using c3.js and have a donut chart that has custom text inside the donut as you hover over each category.  I got that all working great.

I have some custom elements relating to the chart but are detached from the chart completely... if user hovers on those custom elements, i need to trigger a hover over a specific donut arc so the "onmouseover" triggers and the middle of donut gets updated as well.

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30],
            ['data2', 120],
        ],
        type: 'donut',
        onmouseover: (d) => { 
          // does stuff to middle of donut not included here
          console.log("onmouseover", d);          
        }
    },
    donut: {
        title: "custom data here"
    },
    
});

// i want to highlight and run onmouseover for specific chart arc
$('.custom-bars .bar').hover(
  function() {  
    var id = $(this).data('id');
        console.log('trigger ' + id +  ' arc hover state');
    
  }, function() {
    // remove hover
  }
);
```

```css
.custom-bars .bar {
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-bars">
   <div class="bar bar1" data-id="data1">data1 related stuff</div>
   <div class="bar bar2" data-id="data2">data2 related stuff</div>
</div>

<div id="chart" style="width:100%; height: 350px;"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.3.0/c3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.12/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

so when someone hovers over `.bar1` I want to manually trigger `data1` column on the chart so it highlights that arc and runs the "onmouseover" callback which updates the middle of the donut and everything else I need to do. The handling of generating chart and custom-bars will be in separate class methods.

Comment: Have you considered [`d3.select().dispatch`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/#selection_dispatch)? If that doesn't help, please turn your code into a runnable [mre] so we can better see what you mean

Comment: updated question to include fiddle

Comment: You're using very old version of d3 and c3, so navigating the documentation is difficult, and there are many useful things you don't have access to. Have a look at [`chart.focus("data-1")`](https://c3js.org/reference.html#api-focus) for now

Comment: chart.focus seems to highlight the arch like i wanted thank you!  However, I don't think it triggers the "onmouseover" which is what has the code for that dataset that i need to also run

Comment: chart.revert(); returns the chart to default state after .focus() for anyone interested.

Comment: it seems that i could get the data i'd need by using chart.data.shown('data1'); after using chart.focus('data1');

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/pelluche/2adtw71o/30/

Thanks to Ruben I think I figured out how to manually trigger a donut arc.  I updated my fiddle.  chart.focus() trigger the highlight but it doesn't run the onmouseover, so to grab it's values you can use chart.data.shown().  If someone knows a way to trigger the onmouseover of that arc please let me know.

```
$('.custom-bars .bar').hover(
    function() {  
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var arcData = chart.data.shown(id);
        chart.focus(id);
        console.log(arcData);    
    }, function() {
        chart.revert();
    }
);
```